# Stubbing strategy for multiple web services?

Tags: java, rest, stub, wiremock, stubby4j

We have a business heavy front end to a light web service that interacts with many other web services.

Rather than spinning up 4+ applications each time we're developing something on any of the services we want to have a stubbing framework, one that can be reused for most of the services, allowing for a development (& hopefully reusable for testing) in somewhat isolation.

So stubbing the http requests seems like the best strategy.

I've been looking at [Mockey](https://github.com/clafonta/Mockey/wiki), [stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com) & Wiremock (can't post more links) but wanted to ask for Overflow's perspective and see if those who had gone through a similar challenge had any advice.

Comment: stubby4j (https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j) supports splitting the main YAML stub config file into multiple sub-config YAML files, which allows for more logical & cleaner stub code organization. For example when your application talks to many downstream services or you have multiple engineers/team manage their own respective stubs

Answer (score 0):

I've been using WireMock recently and am very impressed -- it allows very declarative expression of stubbed responses, and verification of requests. It's like Mockito for HTTP. That being said, my use has been primarily in unit and integration tests, and it sounds like you plan on using it as a fake for local development. I suppose it should still work in your case, but I'd be curious to see how well it holds up in practice.

Comment: Yeah, the focus on these stubbing frameworks being used more for testing has me wondering I'm thinking about the problem in the wrong way.

Going to try a few out locally, starting with Mockey as it's reading like the nicest for our problem.

Comment: Usually I've approached this problem by using something like Spring's profiles to swap out stub implementations of the remote service interfaces. That is, if I have a `Service` interface backed by a `WebService`, for the local profile it'll be injected with a `StubService` instead. Verifying the correctness of `WebService` is where I'd use Wiremock or similar during integration testing.